How do I show my macfuse mount in Finder Locations area?
I've successfully compiled hello.c from macFUSE examples and mounted it in  macOS Sonoma.
Although I wasn't able reach my macFUSE mount by navigating with Finder for the first time, this was resolved by specifying -o volname=MyVolumeName in mount options.
Now I expect my volume to appear in Finder sidebar (also known as "Locations") just as for any normal disk, but it is not the case. Is there anything I can do to get it there?
Maybe I have to mount by some specific path, or make any system calls on startup, or pass some specific mount options, e.t.c. I've already tried to mount it in /Volumes/MyVolumeName/ but this didn't helped, and actually even didn't worked.
PS. I'm still not sure if this question belongs to SO or Apple.SE, so please forgive me if I get it wrong.

Fortunately, adding -o local into mount options did the trick for me:
$ ./fuse-hello ./fuse-mount-point/ -o local,volname=MyVolumeName



Thanks for your suggestion. I've added full command specification now. Although it's a kind of custom-written tool (namely hello.c from macFUSE examples), those are directly passed to fuse_main() and common for all macFUSE clients.
